# Beef dripping - how long can it safely be kept for in the fridge

Tags: food-safety, beef

I buy beef dripping in tubs from the butcher - usually use a teaspoon when making a roast or a cottage pie.  It never seems to change colour, or smell; so how long is it safe to keep for?

Comment: The other question asks for bacon, but there is no difference between pork and beef dripping, food-safety wise. Also see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/how-long-does-grease-take-to-go-bad-rancid-when-sitting-out/18225#18225, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37662/how-fast-does-pork-fat-spoil, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17601/how-long-can-i-reuse-this-delicious-bacon-grease-for-cooking/17603#17603

Comment: I don't agree - the fact that the answer may happen to be the same doesn't make the question a duplicate.

Comment: No, it doesn't. But the fact that the difference in context does not make it a different problem does make it a duplicate. Of course, it is a somewhat subjective matter, and while I represent the community, it doesn't seem that others have felt compelled to take a look at the question (and possibly dispute my decision). So I decided to open a Meta discussion. I explained my reasoning in there, and I am interested in what the community has to say. You are welcome to make your case there too. http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/should-we-reopen-the-beef-drippings-question